Maclaurin series for $(1+e^x)^{-1}$ and radius of convergence
I am looking at some exercises in a book. In one of the exercises, we are asked to give the first three terms of the series for $(1+e^x)^{-1}$ and state which values of $x$ the series is convergent. I have found the first three terms to be
$$
\frac{1}{1+e^x} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{1}{48}x^3 + O(x^5)
$$
However, the book says the third term is $\frac{1}{12}x^3$ and that the series converges when $\infty < x < \ln 3$.
I suspect the $1/12$ is just an error, right? But how does one find the convergence criteria, and where does the $\ln 3$ come from?

Look, here you apply asymptotic developpement around $x=0$ but you wanna find a criterion on the radius of convergence where $x>0$.  To be rigourous use directly the expression of each of the $n_th$ order term of the MacLaurin Expansion to see when it converges.  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html.

$\displaystyle\frac 1{1+e^x}=\tfrac 12\Big(1-\tanh(\tfrac x2)\Big)$ and series can be expressed via Bernoulli numbers (e.g. https://www.efunda.com/math/taylor_series/hyperbolic.cfm

The book is full of nonsense. Your expansion can be confirmed by WolframAlpha.
The radius of convergence is $\pi$. By a basic fact from complex analysis, there must be a singularity on the boundary of the convergence domain. The singularities of the functions are where $e^x+1=0\Leftrightarrow x = (2n+1)\pi i, n\in\mathbb Z$. The closest ones to the origin are $\pm \pi i$, thus the radius of convergence is $|\pm \pi i|=\pi$. So the series converges for $0\le|x|<\pi$.
Other than directly computing the derivatives, we can form the expansion:
$$\frac{1}{1+e^x} = \frac{1}{2-(1-e^x)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1-e^x}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1-e^x}{2})^n$$
From here, we can use the expansion $\frac{1-e^x}{2}=-\frac{x+x^2/2+x^3/6+\cdots}{2}$ to figure out the first few coefficients. I guess, the above method is valid when $|\frac{1-e^x}{2}|<1\Rightarrow -\infty <x <\ln 3$, but as pointed out above, this is nonsense. $\ln 3$ is an undercounting, the problem with $-\infty < x$ is because while the above series converges, when you rearrange the terms after expanding $((1-e^x)/2)^n$, it may no longer converge.

Did you mean $0\leqslant|x|<\pi$?

@JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, fixed.
